# Extracting Section of Text File Using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have various output Text files that contain  different lines of text/mixed numbers.

I can use Python to Read/Display the full file - no problem but, I'm having difficulty extracting the section I need.  I've tried many different approaches, including json-syntax but, none seem to work. Several 'hopeful solutions' were from Posts and several are homemade.

I need to extract only a section of info from them and print it.
The section I need does vary in amount of content (from a few lines to about 20) and can be mixed text/numbers and length but, generally they are similar enough to example below.

It seems a simple enough task but, not simple for me, I guess.  Rather than posting Python Codes that didn't work and asking what's wrong with them, I'm hoping for a simple solution/suggestion to this while I still have hair to pull out of my head...

My efforts have included Conditional's to test for Start_Text "(additional \n" and ") \n"  for the End_text (e.g., 'startswith').  But, nothing seems to work for me.

Thanks

**[SOLVED BY OTHER MEANS]**

Comment: In your `test_tup` has no commas between tuple elements. Also `yes`,  `no` `reaction` and others  are not defined.